# Update data in Kinvey Database

Tags: xamarin, kinvey

I want to update data in Kinvey Database. I used Rest API (PUT Method). but it is not working .
Same Authorization token in GET and POST method is working fine. Here is the Error :

> {   "error": "InsufficientCredentials",   "description": "The
>   credentials used to authenticate this request are not authorized to
>   run this operation. Please retry your request with appropriate
>   credentials",   "debug": "" }

Please correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution after wasting my two days.
Kinvey applys permission on collection level. So you have to change that permission.
Here is the reference link.
http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/security#collectionpermissions

Please see the snap, so you can better understand.
[image]

Comment: Thanks sagar. it's working fine. but I want to give full database permission as public ?

Comment: @Harshadcse : If this answer solves you current problem, please mark this as a answer. I have to read doc carefully to check that can we apply permission on full db or not.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.